# cakephp test filter do not execute

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

When I run my test cases for a table it runs ok.

```
bin/phpunit tests/TestCase/Model/Table/ContactsTableTest
```

But if I wouuld like to add a filter it just do not runs any tests

```
bin/phpunit --filter checkDuplicatesOnNames tests/TestCase/Model/Table/ContactsTableTest
```

The output of this is the following:

> PHPUnit 4.7.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Time: 130 ms, Memory: 7.00Mb
>
> No tests executed!

Any guess why is that?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `vendor/bin/phpunit`? Anyways, are you using the `@test` annotation for your test method?

Comment: @ndm I installed phpunit when cakephp 3 was still beta. Dispite the updates composer never created vendor/bin/phpunit file for me. I saw in the cookbook that should be there, but did not find out why I have it elsewhere. I do not use `@test` annotation. Should I do it? I thought filter check for the function name, and it worked earlier.

Comment: Yes, it checks for the method name, but by convention unit test methods must start with `test` (ie `testCheckDuplicatesOnNames`) unless they are using the `@test` annotation.

Comment: @ndm Thank you again. I missed the "test" from method name.